# reduce the thread count for specific process which causes high cpu

Tags: multithreading, powershell, count, cpu

i have to reduce the thread count for specific process which causes high cpu.

(Get-Process -ID XXXX | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads).Count

where xxxx - PID gives me thread count.

I have to reduce the thread count of process which is causing high cpu usage.

Any script or command to reduce Thread count?

Answer (score 2):

> Any script or command to reduce Thread count?

In general, no. The number of threads that are created by any given program is controlled entirely by the program itself. You can't do anything about it unless the program provides some means for you to configure the number of threads that it will use before you start it up, or else it provides some command or web interface that you can use to adjust the thread count at run time.

*IF* the number of threads is configurable or, *IF* it is adjustable on-the-fly, the instructions for how to do that are not likely to be the same as for  any other program. You'll have to get the information either by reading the documentation for the program itself, or else you'll have to mention the name of the program in your question, and maybe somebody who is familiar with it will answer.

Comment: P.S., I am assuming that somebody _told you_ to reduce the CPU load, but note! High CPU usage is not, in and of itself, a bad thing. If a compute-intensive application is _not_ using 100% of the available CPU, then you may not be getting your money's worth out of the hardware that you bought to run it on.

Comment: Requirement was to create fake cpu usage,i was able to do that and look for thread count as well, now i have to reduce the thread count and show the reduction in cpu usage. i have created fake high cpu usage using this command "$result = 1; foreach ($number in 1..2147483647) {$result = $result * $number}"

Comment: OK, Looks like I completely misunderstood your question. If _you_ wrote the program, then the way to reduce the thread count is to change the program so that it doesn't create so many threads. If you need to do that at run-time, then you will need some means to provide input to the program (e.g., a simple command-line or GUI) and you will need to implement some means for the CLI thread/GUI thread to signal other threads to tell them when it is time for them to shut down.